# Spring MVC Beginner First app - 404 Error inspite of successful (apparently) handler mapping message from Tomcat in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Deployed a form-based Spring MVC app.Successful build and start of tomcat,but getting 404 error.

Web.xml

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>

    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>

</context-param>

<listener>

    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

</listener>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

<context:component-scan base-package="com.concretepage.controller" />

```
  <property name="prefix" value="/pages/"/>

  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
```

LoginController class:-

package com.concretepage.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

public class LoginController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String login(){

    return "redirect:pages/login.jsp";

}

@RequestMapping(value="pages/userCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String userCheck(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String name=request.getParameter("name");

    String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");

    if("concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(name)&&"concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(pwd)){

        model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully logged in.");

    }else{

        model.addAttribute("message", "Username or password is wrong.");

    }

    return "redirect:success.jsp";

}
```

}`

pom.xml  snippet

```
  <plugins>

    <plugin>

        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>3.3.1</version>

    </plugin>

</plugins>

<finalName>spring-mvc</finalName>
```

Tomcat's server.xml snippet

Tomcat server console log's last bits:

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean

INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh

INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Mar 31 23:13:38 IST 2022]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions

INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters

INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons

INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2043b035: defining beans [loginController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2330a036

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.*] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/login/] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/pages/userCheck] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/pages/userCheck.*] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler

INFO: Mapped URL path [/pages/userCheck/] onto handler 'loginController'

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean

INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 194 ms

Mar 31, 2022 11:13:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload

INFO: Reloading Context with name [/spring-mvc] is completed`your text`

This is my first MVC app with a login and a sucess jsp.Getting a dreaded 404 error.Confusing bit it the console log shows the dispatchservlet handlers initializing and mapping well (obviously am missing something here)

```
             Any folks have any clue as to what's happening ?. I suspect it has to be mapping url issue;tried different  combos.Thanks in advance
```

Comment: No one uses Spring XML and web.xml anymore. You need a different tutorial that’s not written in 2005.

Comment: I understand now an implementation of WebApplicationInitializer  is used and then the onStartup() methos is used to register and map to the dispatcher, but want to try out the old way first.Thanks for the pointer.